# Python combine two lists of objects recursively by comparing datetimes

Tags: python, list, datetime, recursion, merge

Following on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753074/python-create-list-of-objects-from-multiple-files-showing-intersection/), I'm now reading from two files A and B, and putting dates from 2009 into a list of AB2 objects (subAB) in the first non-2009 row before it.

```
class AB2(object):
    def __init__(self, datetime, a=False, b=False):
        self.datetime = datetime
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.subAB = []
```

**For example:**

```
file A: 20111225, 20111226, 20090101
file B: 20111225, 20111226, 20090101, 20090102, 20111227, 20090105
```

Should result in: (square brackets show subAB list)

```
AB2(20111225, a = true, b = true, [])
AB2(20111226, a = true, b = true, 
    [AB2(20090101, a = true, b = true, []),
     AB2(20090102, a = false, b = true, [])], 
AB2(20111227, a = false, b = true, 
    [AB2(20090105, a = false, b = true)])
```

---

Unfortunately, this complicates the previous solution:

```
list_of_objects = [(i, i in A, i in B) for i in set(A) | set(B)]
```

Because:

- Order is important (2009 items go into the first 2011 item before it in the file)
- There can be multiple items of the same datetime in the files
- Now interested in the list of subAB objects also

Due to these reasons, we can't use set as it currently exists (as it removes duplicates and loses order). I've explored using the [OrderedSet recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/), but I can't think of a way to apply it here.

**My current code:**

```
listA = open_and_parse(file A) # list of parsed dates
listAObjects = [AB2(dt, True, None) for dt in listA] # list of AB2 Objects from list A
nested_listAObjects = nest(listAObjects) # puts 2009 objects into 2011 ones
<same for file B>
return combine(nested_listAObjects, nested_listBObjects)
```

Nest method: (puts 2009 items into the previous 2011 item. Ignores 2009 items if they're at the start of the file)

```
def nest(list):
    previous = None
    for item in list:       
        if item.datetime.year <= 2009:
            if previous is not None:
                previous.subAB.append(item)
            else:
                previous = item

    return [item for item in list if item.datetime.year > 2009]
```

But I'm a little stuck on my `combine` function:

```
def combine(nestedA, nestedB):
    combined = nestedA + nestedB
    combined.sort(key=lambda x: x.datetime)

    <magic>

    return combined
```

At this point, without magic, `combined` would look like this:

```
AB2(20111225, a = true, b = None, []) # \ 
AB2(20111225, a = None, b = true, []) # / these two should merge to AB2(20111225, a = true, b = true, [])
AB2(20111226, a = true, b = None, 
    [AB2(20090101, a = true, b = None, []),
     AB2(20090102, a = true, b = None, [])], 
AB2(20111226, a = None, b = true, 
    [AB2(20090101, a = None, b = true, [])], 
# The above two lines should combine, and so should their subAB lists (but only recurse to that level, not infinitely)
AB2(20111227, a = None, b = true, 
    [AB2(20090105, a = None, b = true)])
```

I hope it's ok for me to post a new question - it'll be a completely different solution to my previous one. Also sorry for the long post, I thought it was better to explain all of what I'm doing, so that you can fully understand the problem, and perhaps offer an alternative solution to the whole problem, not to just the `combine` method. Thanks!

---

**Edit: Clarification:**

Basically, I'm checking logs from two connected computers, and comparing whether they both shut down at a particular time, or just one. The computers boot up in 2009 time (but not always Jan 1 - sometimes Jan 4 etc) if they reset before they can retrieve real 2012 time. Therefore, I'm trying to associate the subsequent 2009 shutdowns with the previous one, so that I'll know when it's resetting rapidly.

The 2011/2012 dates *should* be sorted, but the 2009 ones aren't. A log file (`fileA` in my example) for one computer may look like the following:

```
2011/12/15
2011/12/17
2011/12/19 # Something goes wrong, and causes the computer to reset 5 times rapidly
2009/01/01 
2009/01/01
2009/01/04
2009/01/01
2011/12/20 # And everything is better again
2011/12/25
```

In reality, they're actually datetimes (eg `2009/01/01 01:57:01`), so I can simply compare if two datetimes are within a certain `timedelta`.

I'm after either a cleaner overall solution/approach, or a particular solution to the problem of combining these two lists of `AB2` objects.

The easiest method for combining the two would be to iterate through the sorted combined list (with 2009 objects already put into their parents), comparing if the next item is the same date as current one, and creating a new list from these items.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you want to match dates from A and B. The files are not sorted, but do all non-2009 dates occur in ascending order? Can there be multiple occurences of a non-2009 date?

Comment: *I hope it's ok for me to post a new question* - When it's a new question, posting a new question is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: @JanneKarila Sorry it wasn't clear, I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets a little tricky with the comparisons and there's probably a cleaner way of doing it, but this seems to work and should be relatively efficient.

I'm assuming that the order of the dates is important. The increasing dates are compared from the two input streams and combined, when previous dates occur, they are collected, combined and appended to the previous larger date.

I've just created tuples instead of instances of your `AB2` class in this example for brevity.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
fileA = StringIO("""20111225, 20111226, 20090101""")
fileB = StringIO("""20111225, 20111226, 20090101, 20090102, 20111227, 20090105""")

def fileReader(infile):
  for line in infile:
    for part in line.split(','):
      yield part.strip()

def next_or_none(iterable):
  for value in iterable:
    yield value
  yield None

def combine(a,b):
  current_val = None
  hasA = hasB = False
  next_a, next_b = next_or_none(a).next, next_or_none(b).next
  current_a, current_b = next_a(), next_b()
  while True:
    if current_val is None:
      if current_a == current_b:
        current_val = current_a
        hasA = hasB = True
        current_a, current_b = next_a(), next_b()
      elif current_a is not None and (current_b is None or current_a < current_b):
        current_val = current_a
        hasA = True
        current_a = next_a()
      elif current_b is not None and (current_a is None or current_b < current_a):
        current_val = current_b
        hasB = True
        current_b = next_b()
      else:
        break
    else: # There's a current_val
      sub_a = []
      while current_a is not None and current_a < current_val:
        sub_a.append(current_a)
        current_a = next_a()
      sub_b = []
      while current_b is not None and current_b < current_val:
        sub_b.append(current_b)
        current_b = next_b()
      if sub_a or sub_b:
        sub_ab = list(combine(sub_a,sub_b))
      else:
        sub_ab = []
      yield (current_val,hasA,hasB,sub_ab)
      current_val = None
      hasA = hasB = False

for row in combine(fileReader(fileA),fileReader(fileB)):
  print row
```

Yields:

```
('20111225', True, True, [])
('20111226', True, True, [('20090101', True, True, []), ('20090102', False, True, [])])
('20111227', False, True, [('20090105', False, True, [])])
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, thanks! I'm having a little trouble fully understanding it tonight, but I'll give it a crack tomorrow morning and see how I go :)